# How would I do this SQL query with nodejs sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I recently started using Sequelize for my Nodejs (express) backend of my VueJS project

The sql query below gives me what I need from my database (mysql) but I don't know how to translate this to Sequelize
can anybody help me?

```sql
SELECT u.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ui.instrument_name ORDER BY ui.instrument_name) 
AS instruments 
FROM Users u 
INNER JOIN user_instruments ui 
ON ui.user_id = u.id 
INNER JOIN Instruments i 
ON i.instrument_name = ui.instrument_name 
GROUP BY u.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the raw sql query in sequelize by using query method.

meaning you can use this as your query directly by

sequelize.query('YOUR SQL QUERY')

checkout the sequelize doc [link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/raw-queries.html)